# Office 365/Sharepoint API

Tags: winforms, sharepoint-2013, office365, onedrive

I was wondering if anyone could help me. I'm looking to create a winform application which will upload documents into Onedrive for Business.

I'm currently running a trial and from what I can see Onedrive is a document library in Sharepoint. Looking at this I guess I can just use the sharepoint api.

Is there away, when you create a users in office 365 it creates a personal site automatically with out the logging in?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get your question right: You're saying that as an admin, you want to create a user in Office 365 and you want the OneDrive for Business for that user to be provisioned/created without that user having to log in at all.

That's possible. Check out this C# code snippet that does exactly this scenario: http://blog.blksthl.com/2014/08/07/office-365-guide-series-provision-onedrive-for-business-using-powershell/

(The code is for a powershell script, but you can easily adapt it to C# since it pretty much uses powershell to run the C# snippet inside of it)

By the way, instead of using the Sharepoint API, you could also check out the Office 365 Files API which uploads documents into OneDrive for Business. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn605900%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Let me know if you have any questions.